# How to pass input to the regression CNN model which is having multiple output layers?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, regression, tensorflow-datasets

I am having the CNN network using ResNet50 as the backbone. At the end fully connected network, it is having 146 different output layers where each layer responsible for predicting one single (x, y) coordinate.
Please refer model code below:

```html
inputs = Input(input_shape)

    backbone = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_tensor=inputs)

    for layer in backbone.layers:
        if isinstance(layer, BatchNormalization):
            layer.trainable = True
        else:
            layer.trainable = False
            
    x = backbone.output
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    outputs = [Dense(2, activation="sigmoid", name="l"+str(i))(x) for i in range(1, 147)]
    
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Comment: Why not just `Dense(146)`? It's literally the same except it makes the model syntactically easier to handle.

Comment: Oh I just realized, if you want to predict *coordinates* you have to double that. So either `[Dense(2)(x) for i in range (146)]` (not recommended) or `Dense(292)(x)`.

Comment: I have tried already with the single output layer having 292 output neurons, but it is not helping me to create the best model and it is getting overfit. So I am in search of the technique I can use to pass the input to this multi output layered model.

Comment: No I tell you this is literally the same. You have to look elsewhere for regularization techniques.